# All pairs maximally disjoint paths algorithm

Tags: optimization, graph, time-complexity, graph-algorithm

Suppose that there are multiple source destination pairs in an undirected graph. I want to generate disjoint paths for multiple pairs. What would be the complexity of such problem? Is there any polynomial heuristic for finding edge-disjoint paths for these pairs? (i.e. path between s1 and d1 should not have any common edges with the path between s2 and d2)

Comment: There is a shortest-path first greedy algorithm suggested by Kolliopoulos and Stein. I just wondered if there was a better approximation algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a variant of the multi-commodity flow problem:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem

Treat each source/sink pair as a new commodity, and give your edges unit weights to enforce disjoint paths.  Now search the literature for approximations to this class of MCFP with unit capacities.

Comment: Should it be a minimum cost multi-commodity flow problem or a maximum?

Comment: i believe you are interested in the feasibility of satisfying the demand with disjoint paths.  in this case, the costs (objective function) isn't so relevant.  That being said, I would use the minimum cost because this variant tends to have hard demands on the sinks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is NP-hard, even for the case of two sources and two sinks.  It becomes polynomially solvable if you stop caring which source matches with which sink.