# How to find disjoint paths between a set of source and target cells in matrix?

Tags: algorithm, graph, combinatorics

I have a matrix with a set of colored nodes. Each node has is a member of a pair of the same color. The goal is to connect each node with its pair so that all the paths do not intersect. Only orthogonal moves are allowed. Also need to fill all the cells in matrix.
E.g.

[image]

has the following [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xeweg.jpg).

Current solution: recursive algorithm with backtracking trying to make a move for each node in turn until all are connected with their pairs. Also there's a slight optimization for inefficient paths (such as left -> down -> right). This works, though asymptotics is very bad and the example above takes about half a minute to execute.

Do I need any multiflow graph approaches here or is there no efficient solution at all?

Looks similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404033/all-pairs-maximally-disjoint-paths-algorithm), though there's no definite answer yet :(

Comment: It is very easy to create arrangements that are impossible to solve.  e.g.  place red modes in middle of top and bottom rows, place green nodes in middle of left and right columns

Comment: Just up, down and left, right moves are possible

Comment: This is a basic version of the PCB routing problem.  It's hard, but well-studied: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_(electronic_design_automation)

Comment: Thanks for tip!
Looks like the disjoint paths problem for me. And it's solved in polynominal time only for fixed pairs number AFAIU. Though I can hardly implement it if at all possible...
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21973/for-which-values-of-k-is-the-k-disjoint-paths-problem-in-mathcalp